# Is it allowed to ask a question about specific university and department on stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Dear members and moderators, are you allowing questions in this forum about specific PhD programs and scholarship offers? Is it appropriate and ethical to raise a question about some specific department and research members of a PhD program, anecdotal experiences of members on that department, insight of the situation and working environment there, quality of research, professors, students. Scholarship options and working contracts. Can I explicitly mention names, programs, department and discuss about them here?

Answer (score 9):

To answer your questions, I would say (1) no, (2) definitely not, and (3) VERY definitely not.

You can peruse the [on-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) FAQ sections to see what we look for in questions. We definitely don't want anyone to publicly call anyone else out. We are a community where you can seek advice, but we cannot take any action... we're just strangers on the internet. You can ask questions here about what direction to take but please keep them anonymous and as factual as possible. "He said she said" or "I'm ticked off because" will rarely improve a question.

If you need action to be taken, you should go to your university administration.

Comment: I understand, anyway many of you use real life photos or  names,

Comment: @SSimon: There is a huge difference between voluntarily revealing private information about yourself and having that information unsolicitedly revealed by others.

Comment: If I use my real name for obtaining any sort of information about specific institution @Wrzlprmft how that not give me right to "call anyone else out?" if I want to know more about specific institution and I dont mind anonymous profiles, why is not aloud to ask this question?

Comment: @SSimon - (1) We're not discussing what is your "right", we're discussing what is acceptable behavior. We expect full professional courtesy from all members of this community. (2) Asking about specific institutions is difficult because any given academic is unlikely to know much about the specifics of one university, and the question is also that much less likely to be useful to other future visitors. I recommend you read the referenced FAQ sections.